# Why $scope.getList() gets invoked on state change of $scope.showList?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

In the below code,

```
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showList">
            Show unordered list
        </label>

        <ng-include src="getList()"></ng-include>
```

`$scope.getList()` gets invoked on change of `$scope.showList` by check or uncheck, where `$scope.showList` is used as,

```
app3.controller('gListCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.getList = function(){
        return $scope.showList ? "ulgrocerylist.html" : "grocerylist.html";
    };
});
```

Why `$scope.getList()` gets invoked on change of state of `$scope.showList`?

Similar code,

```
        <p>
            <button ng-disabled="disableButton">Button</button>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox"
                    ng-model="disableButton">DisableButton
        </p>
```

make sense to me, because `disableButton` state is changing, so button gets disabled or enabled due to two way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You're a little bit incorrect on your question. The `$scope.getList()` function gets invoked not only on a state change, but on every digest cycle. Let me explain.

Because the framework has absolutelly no clue what code is in the `getList` function. It does not statically analize your code, since it would be both very hard and very inneficient. Due to the nature of how you can use AngularJS, you could be changing the output of `getList` according to a variable in a completely different controller, service, scope, etc. Thus, this output might need to be rerendered upon every digest cycle. AngularJS recognizes this, because you have the function call in your template and calls it on every digest to check whether it needs to swap out the template.

Consider this application structure:

```
<div ng-app="testTest">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <div>Hello world!</div>
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="templateViewer">
    <div>
      <div ng-include="content()"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="templateChanger">
    <button ng-click="handleClick()">Show / hide content</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this code to wire it:

```
var app = angular.module('testTest', []);
app.factory('template', function() {
  return {
    show: false
  };
});
app.controller('templateChanger', function($scope, template) {
  $scope.handleClick = function() {
    // toggle showing of template
    template.show = !template.show;
  };
});
app.controller('templateViewer', function($scope, template) {
  // if the result of this function is not re-evaluated on every digest cycle,
  // Angular has no idea whether to show or hide the template.
  $scope.content = function() {
    return template.show ? 'template.html' : '';
  };
});
```

So, the framework needs to rely on this constant re-evaluation of properties and functions that are binded to the templates in the HTML. Since all the data structures that you use are plain javascript objects, and you don't explicitly tell the framework that something in your viewmodel has changed (as you would do by invoking `set()` methods on your models in other frameworks, such as Backbone or Ember) – angular has to check all variables and re-run all the functions that could possibly change the look of your view, and `ng-include` is one of these cases.

Comment: I understand the `getList()` getting invoked on every digest cycle. But, as you said above,  *`$scope.getList()` function gets invoked not only on a state change of `$scope.showList`*? or *`$scope.getList()` function does not get invoked on a state change of `$scope.showList`*?

Comment: `$scope.getList()` gets called because of the digest cycle. It doesn't matter whether you change the state of `$scope.showList` or not. In fact, `$scope.showList` get's it's state changed, because of the digest cycle, not the other way arround. When you use `ng-model` with the `input` directive, AngularJS triggers a digest cycle, whenever you toggle the checkbox in view. That digest iteration then changes the value of `$scope.showList` (it reads whether the checkbox is checked from view (HTML) and sets the boolean value of `$scope.showList` accordingly). Then reruns `$scope.getList()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use watcher or observe events on showList variable value changes.